# How to run java command as root?

Tags: java, bash, root

I get the infamous error *"Could not find or load main class..."* when I am trying to run `java` command as root.

I tried [this solution](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/can%27t-run-java-as-root-800558/) without any success.

`which java` returns `/usr/bin/java` so I tried appending at ˜/.bashrc

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/java`

or

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin`, again... without success.

ps: *I want to run as root because I've created a simple server using sockets and I want to ping it with an android app. The problem is that I am getting permission denied.*

Comment: Nope @Krease...

Comment: Check if the  $CLASSPATH is still set, when you change your uid to root.

Comment: Actually, maybe it's because the program does not match the root's directory. Maybe I have to compile as root as well.

Comment: Exactly, there is no classpath when I am root!

Comment: "maybe I have to compile as root" - no, this is definitely not needed. You can compile anywhere you want.

Comment: Wait -- "could not find or load main class" - java itself is working, but it can't find the classes you're telling it to run. You need to specify the classpath. `java -cp . com.foo.MyMainClass` (or if needed, replace `.` with the fully qualified path)

Comment: `java`lies at /usr/bin also when I am root

Comment: Yes, exactly! @Krease. Should I just export the CLASSPATH? Is that how its done?

Comment: Actually I allready did that in `.bashrc`for normal users. The question then is how to set CLASSPATH for root.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show where (what directory) the classes you want to run are stored, what specific java command you're running, and what is your working directory when you run it.

Comment: `sudo java -cp $CLASSPATH  com.blubber.Bla`

Comment: You've just saved me from editing all the details @Maksim, that's it!

Comment: Will you post an answer @Maksim?

Comment: You should never run Java as root user. This opens a host of security issues as root can do anything on the server. Your process does not need to run as root in order to open sockets.

Comment: *"You should never run Java as root user."* - That is way too strong.  There are a lot of Java applications that can be safely run as root.  But you are correct that running a network-exposed service as root has significant risks ... and the risk analysis / mitigation can be very complicated.

Comment: As it seemed I didn't had to run `java` as root. At the time I was getting a `SecurityException` from the client and thought maybe that was the problem. I found the problem, the android app needed `INTERNET`permission. I run everything locally so that didn't come to mind..@Maksim @Stephen C @John Camerin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could help:

```
sudo java -cp $CLASSPATH com.blubber.Bla
```